# Test cases for DNF normalization: break my code with your test case

Tags: testing, boolean-logic

I'll give up 100 points, once I can put on a bounty, to the first poster that invents a test case breaking my routine for normalizing propositional logic statements into Disjunctive Normal Form. I'll omit the code, as it's pretty long, and you can treat the routine as a black box anyway.

**A form is in disjunctive normal form**, when it is a disjunction of conjunction of literals (`p`, `NOT p`): in fact, this is dual to CNF. Examples:

```
(NOT p AND q AND r) OR s OR (NOT t)
p OR q
p OR q OR r OR s OR t
p AND q
p AND q AND r
p
NOT p
```

while

```
p AND (q OR r)
p OR (q AND (r OR s))
NOT (p AND q)
```

are not in DNF.

**As for test cases I came up with myself**, I could divide them into

- smoke tests with simple formulas already in DNF such as: `p`, `NOT p`, `(p AND q) or r`;
- cases of `.. AND (..OR..)`, with AND and OR "swapped"; for example, `p AND (q OR r)`'s dnf can be `(p AND q) OR (p AND r)`;
- having the same operator twice on a path in the tree, ie. `.. OR ( .. AND ( .. OR .. ))`;
- in particular, with no other operator in between `.. OR ( .. OR .. )`;
- having multiple negations at different places places in the formula, `... NOT NOT p`, `NOT NOT (.. AND ..)`;
- formulas that look more like a tree, `(.. OR ..) AND (.. AND ..)` rather than just a list `p AND (q AND (r AND ...))`;
- where operators have more than two operands `(...) AND (p OR q OR r OR s)`.

**Having those tests**, I made some simple changes to the code. Apparently I broke the code, because the suite failed. While that means my tests help me, what worries me is that only one of my tests picked up the problem. That is just one test case which if I didn't have, I would miss a bug. For how many bugs I don't even have a single test, then?

So, what would be some good test cases?

Comment: Not really off-topic. Code should rarely be written without the accompanying tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [Fuzz testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing).

1) Generate random statements "((A AND B) OR B)" and pass them thru your DNF normalizer. 
2) Iterate thru all possible values of the inputs (AB=00, 01, 11, 10), testing the answer when evaluating the original expression and the answer from your simplification.
3) Complain loudly if any bad results found.

The only tricky bit is generating random statements. I'd do it with recursion. A simplistic first pass would look like this:

```
gen_one: return one of "A", "B", "NOT A", "NOT B"
gen_op: return one of "AND", "OR", "NOR", "NAND"
genstatement:
  if rand < 10%
    return gen_one()
  else
    return "(" + genstatement() + gen_op + genstatement() + ")"
```

Comment: That's a good idea! I'll give it a shot.